# Five sets and a movie director

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

The letters A to E and the numbers 1 to 7 are according to an order.
**What are the sets A, B, C, D and E?**

> A = {1, 3, 4, 7}
> B = {2, 3, 4, 6}
> C = {1, 2, 7}
> D = {5}
> E = {1, 3, 6}

The clues for numbers 1 to 7 are as given below.
**Which name fills the blank?**

> 1. An Australian singer-songwriter
> 2. The second part of a certain country's name
> 3. A plant genus
> 4. A plant genus
> 5. The International Cat Association
> 6. A 1948 movie directed by _________
> 7. A variant of Leah or Lea

Hint

> Think of two separate lists that are 5 and 7 in number

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start with the 7 numbered clues. These represent the following:

> 1. An Australian singer-songwriter = **[SIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sia)**
>  2. The second part of a certain country's name = **RICA** (Costa Rica)
>  3. A plant genus = **[ERICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erica_(plant))**
>  4. A plant genus = **ERICA** (again)
>  5. The International Cat Association = **TICA** (its acronym)
>  6. A 1948 movie directed by _________ = (to be solved shortly...)
>  7. A variant of Leah or Lea = **LIA**

What are these? They are the:

> endings of the names of **continents**:
>
>  A**SIA**, AF**RICA**, NORTH AM**ERICA**, SOUTH AM**ERICA**, ANTARC**TICA**, ..., AUSTRA**LIA** (in place of 'Oceania').

This means clue 6 must in some way indicate the missing one, and this can be done if it reads:

> 6. A 1948 movie directed by **ALFRED HITCHCOCK** = **[ROPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(film))**
>
>  ...since this is the tail end of the missing continent, EU**ROPE**.

Returning to our 5 sets, what are these? Substitute what the 7 answers represent into their sets to get...

> ...groups of continents. And how are they grouped? In terms of the **oceans that they border**:
>
>  A = {ASIA, NORTH AMERICA, SOUTH AMERICA, AUSTRALIA} = **PACIFIC**
>  B = {AFRICA, NORTH AMERICA, SOUTH AMERICA, EUROPE} = **ATLANTIC**
>  C = {ASIA, AFRICA, AUSTRALIA} = **INDIAN**
>  D = {ANTARCTICA} = **SOUTHERN**
>  E = {ASIA, NORTH AMERICA, EUROPE} = **ARCTIC**

As confirmation, notice that the two lists are complete and ranked in order.

> i.e. There are precisely 7 continents and 5 oceans on Earth, and both the continents and oceans are listed in order of decreasing size.

<sub>One final note:</sub>

> <sub>In my original solution I had 'South AFRICA' as a legitimate solution to #2; however, as @Marius points out in comments, 'Costa RICA' also works here, and is much more satisfying since it does not give the entire name of the continent all at once.</sub>

Comment: (For the record, before the hint I had already solved the 7 but not the 5. The hint pushed me to think in the right direction for the latter part...)

Comment: There are still a lot of us old fogeys that refuse to accept that D exists.

Comment: nice deduction. I have a suggestion if you don't mind. I think for #2, Costa Rica fits better. As it discloses only the suffix as for the rest of the numbers.

Comment: @Marius I like that suggestion a lot - nice thinking :)